# Changes made to users in ADAC vs ADUC not happening

Tags: active-directory

In my organization I have just discovered something: When making certain changes (to users) in the AD Administrative Center (ADAC) GUI, they do not happen, versus making those same changes in ADUC GUI.

For instance, Connect:-ing a Home folder in the GUI for ADUC will create the Home folder as per the server setup. But doing the exact same thing in ADAC (connecting a drive location for the home folder) results in no folder creation. Any idea why?

TL:DR: Why would connecting a Home folder in one Active Directory GUI (the ADAC) not create the folder, while doing the same action in ADUC does create the Home folder? They should just be two GUIs performing the same back-end manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would connecting a Home folder in one Active Directory GUI (the ADAC) not create the folder, while doing the same action in ADUC does create the Home folder?

Because it is the *application* that is creating the folder, not Active Directory.  This is not strictly just a back-end call to Active Directory to perform a task - this is separate task that is performed by ADUC.  If you perform the same task in PowerShell (assigning a home folder), you will notice the folder is not auto-created.

The ADAC does have *some* advantages; however, [this page](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/03/19/four-things-i-like-about-active-directory-administrative-center-adac-in-windows-server-2012/) has a nice synopsis of four things that can be done in ADAC (2012+)

- PowerShell History Viewer
- Active Directory Recycle Bin
- Fine-Grained Password Policy
- Global Search (functionality specific to ADAC)